# How to Always make the ttyUSB0 none root access allowed?

Tags: permissions, security, users

Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit OS.

I have a service running using Python serial the application running without root as username. But it has to access /dev/ttyUSB0 , so i need to do every time manually chmod -R 777 /dev/ttyUSB0

When i reboot the PC again i have to do it manually.

Is there any way automatically make the /dev/ttyUSB0 to ttyUSBxxx always available by any users? So that i do not need to do that manually every single day on reboot?

Comment: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#ownership

Comment: No need for `chmod -R`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Part 0: problem

```
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0 
cat: /dev/ttyACM0: Permission denied
```

Part 1: verify

```
$ id sun
uid=1000(sun) gid=1000(sun) groups=1000(sun),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
$ id -g sun
1000
$ egrep -i "^tty" /etc/group
tty:x:5:
$ egrep -i "^sun" /etc/group
sun:x:1000:
```

Part 2: make it work

```
$ usermod -a -G tty sun
$ id sun
uid=1000(sun) gid=1000(sun) groups=1000(sun),4(adm),5(tty),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),112(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Part 3: problem solved, no more asking permission denied

```
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0
< cursor blinking
```

happy spoon feeding :)